Asking the experts in mathematical logic and set theory for survey articles to supplement the standard textbooks.....
I'm asking this question to the experts in mathematical logic and set theory.I'm a former graduate student in mathematics with an additional background in philosophy engaged in serious self study. I've recently-after a long absence-returned to the serious study of logic and set theory. I've used Peter Smith's wonderful blog and study guide to direct me. I'm using Smith's own general logic book, the classic 1952 textbook by Kleene and Peter Andrews' wonderful but difficult mathematical logic text to get my feet wet. I hope to move on to serious studies of Mendelson and Bell and Machover. In addition,I plan on seriously learning set theory from Smullyan and Fitting and Moschovakis' terrific books and after that,Kunen. After this,hope to study more specialized sources like Hodges' model theory book.Of course, all this depends on how much time is available.
But none of these standard sources are going to bring me anywhere near where the state of research in these fields is.Of course, they're not supposed to, they're standard textbooks designed to teach the basics. My guess is none of them will present material that
was relevant to researchers after the 1970's.
My question: Can any of you recommend comprehensive survey articles of mathematical logic and set theory that begin around the year 2000 and will bring me up to speed in the big picture of how the state of the art of logic and set theory currently looks and what major developments have occurred since the majority of the currently used standard sources were written? These articles should be readable by a first year mathematics graduate student regardless of their level in logic or set theory. Any help in this would be really appreciated.

https://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ests-wh.pdf

+1 Thanks, this is nice for a start-but I need something more comprehensive. Thanks a lot for it,though. I've skimmed through Jech. Despite it's cost, it's so beautifully written, it seems like a waste of time to use anything else once you've got the basics down. But the new edition of Kunen is much cheaper and came highly recommended to me by one of my old logic teachers. It IS much terser then Jech,though.
